# Javascript: If variable mets a condittion defined on another variable

Tags: javascript, if-statement

My problem is simple but I can't find a way to make thag work

The idea is that if a variable (number) mets a condittion defined on another variable (cond), run some code

Example:

```
var cond = '> 4';
var number = 5;
// Some type of if statement to check if 5 is > 4
```

Comment: Lots of solutions. `eval` (bad idea), write a parser, create functions which correlate to the comparison and save the `4` (or whatever value) in a separate variable.

Comment: Have you considered using ternary operator ?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is the use-case for this odd requirement?

Comment: The "right" way to do this sort of dynamic validation is with functions, possibly/probably functions generated with closures.

Comment: @Teemu I want it basically to make my code easy to extend (via objects, not code itself) It may sound very very odd but I know what I'm doing, trust me ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *can* use [`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) but usually if you resort to `eval`, you're not understanding the problem correctly.

```js
var cond = '> 4';
var number = 5;
if (eval(number + cond)) {
  console.log(number + cond);
}
```

Another possibility would be to create functions which correlate with the condition then store the operand in another variable.

```js
var compareFunctions = {
  '>': function(a, b) {
    return a > b;
  }
};

var op = '>';
var operand = 4;
var number = 5;
if (compareFunctions[op](number, operand)) {
  console.log(number + op + operand);
}
```

Comment: Your way seems to be the better ;) Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this?

```
   if (eval(number+cond)){
      console.log("success");
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple, but likely dangerous and ugly way would be to use `eval()`

```js
var cond = '> 5';
console.log(eval(4 + cond));
console.log(eval(6 + cond));
```

However, this is dangerous because if that string is in any way coming from the user, they could enter bad things and make bad things happen.

A more proper way to handle it would be to parse it properly:

```js
let cond = '> 5';
const evaluateCondition = (value, condition) => {
  // Allows for >, <, >=, <=, !=, ==
  let [, operator, operand] = condition.match(/^\s*(>|<|>=|<=|!=|==)\s*(\d+)$/);
  switch(operator) {
      case '>':
        return value > operand;
      case '<':
        return value < operand;
      case '==':
        return value == operand;
      // ... implement other operators here
  }
};

console.log(evaluateCondition(4, cond));
console.log(evaluateCondition(6, cond));
```

This will let you define valid operators and handle them in a safe manner, also easily catching invalid input.

---

Below was done before an edit changed the question.

You have to **declare** the variable outside of it, but you can set it pretty easily. The syntax I would use looks like this:

```
var a = 5, b;
a == 5 && (b = 2);
```

The bit after the `&&` only executes if the first condition is true. To set a variable in a syntax like this, you just wrap it in parentheses.

The more traditional way would be to use an `if` statement:

```
var a = 5, b;
if (a == 5) {
    b = 2;
}
```

If you declare the second variable inside of the `if` statement, it doesn't exist outside of it:

```
var a = 5;
if (a == 5) {
    var b = 2;
}
console.log(b) // undefined
```

which might be what was tripping you up.

Comment: I didn't downvote but I imagine it's because this doesn't solve the problem. The idea is that the condition is defined via a string and from that string they need the correct result.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a function for the check of the condition.

```js
var cond = function (x) { return x > 4; };
var number = 5;

console.log(cond(number));
```

Comment: A good scalable answer: replace setting condition as a string with setting condition as a function.  You might add the advantage of being able to define compound conditions such as `var c =  x => x >0 && x < 4`, difficult to do with a string. (not the downvoter)

Answer (score -1):

You could use eval just be careful and make sure you read up on eval first:

```js
var cond = '> 4';
var number = 5;
console.log(eval(("" + number + cond)));
```